# recv() C error invalid conversion from char to int

Tags: c, linux, type-conversion, recv

I have some C code below:

```
char update[MAX_UPDATE_LEN];
int remoteLen;

char pholder;
pholder = recv(update,connectDescriptor,MAX_UPDATE_LEN,MSG_DONTWAIT); //error
remoteLen = atoi("pholder");
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
client.cpp:849: error: invalid conversion from `char*' to `int'

client.cpp:849: error: initializing argument 1 of `ssize_t recv(int, void*, 
size_t, int)'

client.cpp:849: error: invalid conversion from `int' to `void*'

client.cpp:849: error: initializing argument 2 of `ssize_t recv(int, void*, 
size_t, int)'
```

What is causing these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with this code:

```
char update[MAX_UPDATE_LEN];
int remoteLen;

char pholder;
pholder = recv(update,connectDescriptor,MAX_UPDATE_LEN,MSG_DONTWAIT); <-- error here
remoteLen = atoi("pholder");
```

1. `recv` returns an `ssize_t` which is usually much bigger than a `char`.  So you can't safely store the return code in `pholder`.
2. The arguments to `recv()` are in the wrong order.  Here's the declaration: `ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);`
3. `atoi` is being passed a string which is not a number `"pholder"`.  It expects a string like `"12345"`.  If ASCII-encoded numerals is what you expect, you can give `update` to `atoi`.

Bonus: use `sizeof(update)` instead of `MAX_UPDATE_LEN` for `len` -- that way if the type declaration or size of `update` changes, you should still get the expected value.

Here's how you might fix it:

```
char update[MAX_UPDATE_LEN];

const int flags = MSG_DONTWAIT;
const ssize_t ret = recv(connectDescriptor, update , sizeof(update), flags);
if (-1 == ret)
{
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}
const int remoteLen = strtol(update, update + sizeof(update), 0);
```

Comment: After making some minor adjustments and using Atoi, I got it too work. thanks

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, please mark the question as "answered"